# Cassandra tuple type always frozen?

Tags: cassandra

I read from [Tuple type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/tupleType.html) from Datastax website that Cassandra 3.0 no longer requires the `frozen` keyword for `tuple` types. However, when I use the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE test.tb8 (id int primary key, val tuple<text, text>);
DESCRIBE test.tb8;
```

I got

```
CREATE TABLE test.tb8 (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  val frozen<tuple<text, text>>
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
```

The C* version is

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.1 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Which means I got a `frozen` tuple. Does that mean the tuples are always `frozen` in C* no matter you specify `frozen` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unlike other “composed” types (collections and UDT), a tuple is always
>   frozen (without the need of the frozen keyword) and it is not possible
>   to update only some elements of a tuple (without updating the whole
>   tuple).

[Tuple in Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html#tuples)

Comment: apache cassandra docs is still in progress.. so you might want to refer both